# Wordpress - creating a downloadable CSV File

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I built an import script plugin for a client's Wordpress website. I then built an export script, but the .csv file won't download. I think it's because I'm working within the Wordpress framework?

Here is my code - this file is being included within the plugin:

```
if(isset($_POST["exportcards"])){
    global $wpdb;
    $cards_result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT wp_posts.post_title as `Card Number`, store_selector.meta_value as `Sponsor`, users.user_email as `Card Owner`, users.user_registered as `Date Registered` FROM wp_posts left join wp_postmeta store_selector on wp_posts.ID = store_selector.post_id and store_selector.meta_key = "store_selector" left join wp_postmeta card_owner on wp_posts.ID = card_owner.post_id and card_owner.meta_key = "card_owner" left join wp_users users on card_owner.meta_value = users.id where wp_posts.post_type = "card" LIMIT 0, 10');
    if (! $cards_result) {
        $Error = $wpdb->print_error();
        die("The following error was found: $Error");
    } else {
        $csv_fields=array();
        $csv_fields[] = 'Card Number';
        $csv_fields[] = 'Sponsor';
        $csv_fields[] = 'Card Owner';
        $csv_fields[] = 'Date Registered';
        $output_filename = 'user_cards.csv';
        $output_handle = @fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );
        header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );
        header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
        header( 'Content-type: text/csv' );
        header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $output_filename );
        header( 'Expires: 0' );
        header( 'Pragma: public' ); 
        fputcsv( $output_handle, $csv_fields );
        foreach ($cards_result as $Result) {
            $leadArray = (array) $Result;
            fputcsv( $output_handle, $leadArray );
        }
        fclose( $output_handle );   
        echo "Export successful!";
        die();  
            }
}
?>

<form name="exportcards" id="exportcards_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" >
    <input class="button-primary" type="submit" name="exportcards" id="exportcards_btn" value="Download Cards"  />
</form>
```

When I click on the "Download cards button", it should auto-download a .csv file, but it's not.

If I print_r the results, it executes just fine. I think since we're within the Wordpress framework, the headers can't update.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: not working HOW? maybe you already did output causing all of the header() calls to fail?

Comment: @MarcB The file just isn't downloading

Comment: basic debuggin: start checking if any of that code is actually running...

Comment: @MarcB The code is running and the query is executing properly. The only issue is the file is not saving.

Comment: then check if the fopen call succeeded... using `@` is the programming equivalent of stuffing your fingers in your ears and going "lalalalalala can't hear you".

Comment: @MarcB it's just outputting the csv file on the screen.

Comment: that's good, then it's writing to php://output. which means that probably something in WP has triggered output, causing your header() calls to fail with "headers already sent".

Comment: @MarcB Correct, I think this is because it's being loaded within the Wordpress framework. I'm wondering how to fix this? Or if there's a work-around?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80689/discussion-between-steeped-and-marc-b).